# WSO2 Published API invocation using CORS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, wso2

**What I have?**

1. WSO2 AM 1.9.1 successfully launched on my PC

   - Mgt Console URL  : my-localhost:9443/carbon/
   - API Publisher Default Context : my-localhost:9763/publisher
   - API Store Default Context : my-localhost:9763/store
2. Simple UI (jQuery) app launched on my-localhost:8080/

**What I need?**

1. Invoke [WS02 Published APIs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Published+APIs) (login to Publisher, publish new API, etc) from my jQuery app using ajax.

**Code example**

```
    $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://192.168.33.151:9763/publisher/site/blocks/user/login/ajax/login.jag',
        data: {
            action: 'login',
            username: 'admin',
            password: 'admin'
        },
        complete: function(a, b) {
            console.log(a);
            console.log(b);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

**Issue**

Always when I perform ajax query to published APIs I get CORS security error.

```
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load my-localhost:9763/publisher/site/blocks/user/login/ajax/login.jag. Origin my-localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I've tried to change api-manager.xml to the following, but it didn't help me:

```
<CORSConfiguration>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Access-Control-Allow-Origin>*</Access-Control-Allow-Origin>
    <Access-Control-Allow-Headers>authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Content-Type</Access-Control-Allow-Headers>

    <!--Configure Access-Control-Allow-Methods-->
    <Access-Control-Allow-Methods>GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS</Access-Control-Allow-Methods>

</CORSConfiguration>
```

Also as WSO2 use Tomcat, I've tried to add Tomcat CORS filter -org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter and map to the /* url. But it also didn't help.

**Any idea?**

Comment: Try putting <Access-Control-Allow-Origin>http://my-localhost:9763,http://my-localhost:8080,http://my-localhost:9443,http://my-localhost:8080,[ip]:8080</Access-Control-Allow-Origin> from http://blog.lakmali.com/2014/11/troubleshooting-issues-with-swagger-in.html

Comment: I've already tried it, but it didn't help also. We can't invoke publisher api from JS another domain.

Comment: We want to sent ajax request from the third-party app to the default published Store or Publisher APIs (not published by the user), such as login, logout, getAllApis and so on.